# How to create an array-like class compatible with NumPy ufuncs?

Tags: python, numpy, automatic-differentiation

I'm trying to implement [Automatic Differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) using a class that behaves like a NumPy array. It does *not* subclass `numpy.ndarray`, but contains two array attributes. One for the value, and one for the Jacobian matrix. Every operation is overloaded to operate both on the value and the Jacobian. However, I have trouble making NumPy ufuncs (e.g., `np.log`) work on my custom "array".

I have created the following minimal example, illustrating the issue. `Two` is supposed to be a radiation hardened version of a NumPy array, which computes everything twice, and makes sure the results are equal.

It must be support indexing, element-wise logarithm, and length. Just like a normal `ndarray`. The element-wise logarithm works fine when called using `x.cos()`, but does something unexpected when called using `np.cos(x)`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

class Two(object):
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        print("init with", val1, val2)
        assert np.array_equal(val1, val2)
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2

    def __getitem__(self, s):
        print("getitem", s, "got", Two(self.val1[s], self.val2[s]))
        return Two(self.val1[s], self.val2[s])

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<<{}, {}>>".format(self.val1, self.val2)

    def log(self):
        print("log", self)
        return Two(np.log(self.val1), np.log(self.val2))

    def __len__(self):
        print("len", self, "=", self.val1.shape[0])
        return self.val1.shape[0]

x = Two(np.array([1,2]).T, np.array([1,2]).T)
```

Indexing returns the relevant elements from both attributes, as expected:

```
>>> print("First element in x:", x[0], "\n")
init with [1 2] [1 2]
init with 1 1
getitem 0 got <<1, 1>>
init with 1 1
First element in x: <<1, 1>>
```

Element-wise logarithm works just fine when called using `x.cos()`:

```
>>> print("--- x.log() ---", x.log(), "\n")
log <<[1 2], [1 2]>>
init with [ 0.  0.69314] [ 0.  0.69314]
--- x.log() --- <<[ 0.  0.69314], [ 0.   0.69314]>>
```

However, `np.log(x)` doesn't work as expected. It realizes the object has a length, so it extracts every item and takes the logarithm on each one, then returns an array of Two objects (dtype=object).

```
>>> print("--- np.log(x) with len ---", np.log(x), "\n") # WTF
len <<[1 2], [1 2]>> = 2
len <<[1 2], [1 2]>> = 2
init with 1 1
getitem 0 got <<1, 1>>
init with 1 1
init with 2 2
getitem 1 got <<2, 2>>
init with 2 2
len <<[1 2], [1 2]>> = 2
len <<[1 2], [1 2]>> = 2
init with 1 1
getitem 0 got <<1, 1>>
init with 1 1
init with 2 2
getitem 1 got <<2, 2>>
init with 2 2
len <<[1 2], [1 2]>> = 2
len <<[1 2], [1 2]>> = 2
init with 1 1
getitem 0 got <<1, 1>>
init with 1 1
init with 2 2
getitem 1 got <<2, 2>>
init with 2 2
log <<1, 1>>
init with 0.0 0.0
log <<2, 2>>
init with 0.693147 0.693147
--- np.log(x) with len --- [<<0.0, 0.0>> <<0.693147, 0.693147>>]
```

If `Two` has no length method, it works just fine:

```
>>> del Two.__len__
>>> print("--- np.log(x) without len ---", np.log(x), "\n")
log <<[1 2], [1 2]>>
init with [ 0.          0.69314718] [ 0.   0.693147]
--- np.log(x) without len --- <<[ 0.   0.693147], [ 0.          0.693147]>>
```

How can I create a class that meets the requirements (getitem, log, len)? I researched subclassing `ndarray`, but that seemed to be more complicated than it is worth.

Also, I could not find the location in the NumPy source code where  `x.__len__` is accessed, so I'm interested in that too.

Edit: I'm using miniconda2 with Python 2.7.11 and NumPy 1.11.0.

Comment: Look at how `np.ma` implements masked arrays.  It's subclass, but contains 2 arrays, the data and the mask.  Most of the code is about creating and coordinating the 2 attributes.  Most calculations are performed by compressing or filling the data so regular array methods work.  `scipy.sparse` is another example of array like objects that contain arrays.  But it implements most of its own calculations, with key ones like matrix product coded in C.

Comment: The details are still being fleshed out, but take a look at [this NEP](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/neps/ufunc-overrides.html), which tries to solve the exact problem you are describing. I think it is partly implemented in one of the latest numpy releases, although it is experimental and likely to change in the near future.

Comment: Thanks. `np.ma` seems incredibly complicated (and is a subclass), but `scipy.sparse` looks better. It does not subclass `ndarray` and avoids the problems above by not implementing `__len__`, but this is probably acceptable for me, since users can use `shape[0]`. If the NEP is implemented all my problems would go away it seems.

Comment: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py` has the code for ` __numpy_ufunc` as described in the NEP.  It's because of that that `np.dot(A,A)` works for sparse matrices.